# Load selected fields from ArrayList to ListView.

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, cursor

I would like to load only selected fields from my ArrayList to ListView.
I couldn't find that example so I ask.

I have an ArrayList of a structure as follows:

```
ArrayList<LogInfo> logInfoArray
```

Where LogInfo class have fields as follows:

```
public ArrayList<Point[][]> strokes;
public LinkedList<byte[]> codes;
public int[] times; //contains fields of calendar class
```

I want to put in my ListView in each row selected fields from "times" and "codes"

How can I achieve that? I would like to use a cursor, if possible.

Comment: I think you may be looking for a custom SimpleAdapter. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom adapter extending from `ArrayAdapter` to which you can pass the `ArrayList<LogInfo>` .

You can then ovverride the `getView(..)` method of the Adapter to set the fields you want in the row of the `Listview` .

**UPDATE**

From this example at [Android Custom Adapters](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom)

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LogInfo> {

  private final List<LogInfo> list;
  private final Activity context;

  public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<LogInfo> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
  }

  static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text1, text2;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
      view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
      final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label1);
      viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label2);

      view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
      view = convertView;

    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text1.setText(list.get(position).getName1());
    holder.text2.setText(list.get(position).getName2());
    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how getView() method should look like? And how can I use that adapter? I did a tuorial from Android site and also one from internet but I am still a newbie in that topic.